# Should the tags /scripting and /shell-script be merged?

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms

There are these two - [scripting](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/scripting) and [shell-script](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/shell-script). Moreover,

- [scripting](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/scripting) is synonymous with [script](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/script) and [non-interactive](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/non-interactive)
- [shell-script](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/shell-script) is synonymous with [bash-script](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bash-script) and [shell-scripting](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/shell-scripting)

I'm wondering what's the point of having the two of these separate. If a script is not a shell script, then it's more about programming than Unix/Linux. Right?

I don't mind having a separate [scripting](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/scripting) tag, but would like to clarify the usage.

Comment: I, too, have wondered this. Maybe scripting could cover python, awk, perl, and other languages that aren't typically login shells like ksh, zsh, bash, etc?

Comment: @JeffSchaller They've not been used consistently. Similar questions are either /shell-script + /bash and /scripting + /bash.

Comment: Agreed, which is why I upvoted your Q and wondered about possible usage guidance.

Comment: @JeffSchaller If I were to vote for a solution, I'd go for a merge under the /scripting or /script banner. Shell scripts need a specifying tag describing the interpreter. So do non-shell scripts. I'd add this directive to the tag's usage info. Otherwise they will be cross-misused both ways.

Comment: To me, scripting is the use of any interpreted programming language.  While /shell-script definitely falls into that, it's actually more of a subset.  Python and Ruby scripts are common in newer systems, and AWK is common in older systems.  While some would say these are programming languages, so are the modern shells.